# Can I use Google Maps to tell me how many times I have been to a specific place?

Tags: google-maps

I would like to see how many times I went to my local gym to see whether it's worth paying their monthly sub or whether I should just pay every time I go there. Is it possible to do that with maps? I tried but was unable to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use Google's Timeline to get the times I've been to a specific location?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/102899/can-i-use-googles-timeline-to-get-the-times-ive-been-to-a-specific-location)

Answer (score 5):

Visit https://www.google.com/maps/timeline and it will show you all the location data Google has for you. At the lower left corner, there is a link to see your most visited places, which will tell you the first time you visited and how many times subsequently.

Comment: This is nice and does show the number of times, times of the day but doesn't list the dates of visit. Would be really useful if it could do that! If you do implement this, thanks in advance Ben!